# How to swap a number of the values between 2 columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, swap, percentage

I have a matrix with the size of 10x100. How can I swap the values between column 1 and column 10 in the first 40% of the rows?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
A = rand(10,100);

A(round(1:0.4*size(A,1)),[1,10]) = A(round(1:0.4*size(A,1)),[10,1]);
```

Comment: This swaps 40% of the columns, not 40% of the rows. And swaps columns 1 and 2, not columns 1 and 10.

Comment: A minor improvement: `A(1:round(0.4*size(A,1)),[1,10]) = A(1:round(0.4*size(A,1)),[10,1]);` may be slightly faster